# Typescript interface to be either null or a specific object

Tags: typescript

I have a TS error that complains of a null value because of this interface:

```
interface Info {
  active?: boolean;
  id?: string;
}
```

Which will obviously complain when trying to use state like this:

```
const [info, setInfo] = useState<Info>(null);
```

Is there a way of allowing the entire object itself to also be null (note: not specific object keys)? I've tried this:

```
const [info, setInfo] = useState<Info | null>(null);
```

I'm using it with react. Thanks for any help

Comment: `const [info, setInfo] = useState<Info | null>(null);` isn't this working?

Comment: complain ```null```? I think it should complain for ```undefined``` as those properties are optional

Comment: What happens if you use an empty Object instead of null like {}

Comment: not sure why it the real equivalent of the example given here did not work, but it worked when I gave it an existing type that had other compulsory keys that weren't present in this object. Wierd. Thanks for your suggestions anyway